# Oracle Forms: How can I develop a form which does not allow Insert but allows Update?

Tags: properties, insert, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have Master-Detail Oracle form. The requirement in not to allow insertion on the table through the form. It can allow Update though. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

On the block level there are properties you can adjust.
One of these options is under the database level "insert allowed" and "update allowed"
If you set insert allowed to No, then you won't be able to insert into your block.

Regards

Comment: I've tried this. Setting this property "Insert Allowed" to 'No' is not allowing me to update even of the "Update allowed" is set to 'yes'. I want to able to still update values in my form.

Comment: you have to make sure on the item level you set the item enabled and navigable and also update allowed on this level.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by setting insert and update property on PRE-INSERT and ON-INSERT triggers and it was working as expected. But now I've used WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM on an item and the update is not happening now. Don't know what is it changing.